# JQuery Validation Empties JS Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation to validate a form in a ASP.NET MVC application.
I am using Ajax to submit a form, the form has several basic fields but also builds a js object which
needs to be submitted to the controller.

The problem I'm having is when I am using the submit handler on the jQuery validation,
its clears the JS object I've built.

I checked the object just before the validation and it is accurate.
I then checked the object using the before send on the ajax method and it has emptied.

```
   $('#FATTemplateForm').validate({

            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                //check whether chosen plugin is initialized for the element
                if (element.attr("name") == "PORRadio") {
                    error.insertAfter("#POROption");
                }
                else if (element.attr("name") == "UPN")
                {
                    error.insertAfter("#UPN-Chosen");
                }
                else if (element.attr("name") == "ComponentTypeInput")
                {
                    error.insertAfter("#componetType-Chosen");
                }
                else if (element.attr("name") == "ComponentAttributeTypeInput")
                {
                    error.insertAfter("#FATAttributes-Chosen");
                }
                else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {

                var errors = this.numberOfInvalids(); // <- NUMBER OF INVALIDS

                var summary = "You have " + errors + " validation errors. Please fix errors and try submitting again.";
                $('#ErrorMsg').empty().append(summary);
                $('.alert-danger').show()

                this.defaultShowErrors(); // <- ENABLE default MESSAGES
               
              
            },
            invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
              
            },



            rules: {
                //Select System/Component
                ParentChildInput: {
                    required: true,
                },

                ComponentTypeInput: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function (element) {
                            if ($('#formParentChild').val() == "Component") {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                },
                OtherComponentTypeNameInput: {

                    required: {
                        depends: function (element) {
                            if ($('#formComponentType').val() == "Other") {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                ComponentAttributeTypeInput: {

                    required: {
                        depends: function (element) {
                            if ($('#formComponentType').val() == "Other") {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },

                Project: {
                    required: true,
                },

                UPN: {
                    required: true,
                },

                Disciplines: {
                    required: true,
                },

                DrawingRefernceNameInput: {
                    required: false,
                },

                PORRadio: {
                    required: true,
                },

                PORNumNameInput: {

                    required: {
                        depends: function (element) {

                            if ($("input:radio[name='PORRadio']:checked").val()=="1") {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                PORRevNameInput: {

                    required: {
                        depends: function (element) {
                            if ($("input:radio[name='PORRadio']:checked").val() == "1") {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    digits: true,
                },
                PORDateNameInput: {

                    required: {
                        depends: function (element) {
                            if ($("input:radio[name='PORRadio']:checked").val() == "1") {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },

                DrawingRefernceNameInput: {

                    regx: /^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./%^()!#&"'+-]*$/,
                }

                //OtherComponentTypeNameInput:
                //{
                //    required: true
                //},
                //ComponentAttributeTypeInput:
                //{
                //    required: true
                //},
            },
            messages: {},
            errorElement: 'div',
            errorLabelContainer: '.errorTxt',
            submitHandler: function (form) {
               
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    beforeSend: console(FAT),
                    url: "/FATs/CreateFAT_Template",
                    data: JSON.stringify(FAT),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    headers: headers,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: successFunc,
                    error: errorFunc
                });


                //Success Result
                function successFunc(data, status) {

                    //Redirect User after successful submittion of FAT
                    window.location.href = "/FATs/CreateFATFromTemplateIndex";
                }

                //Error Result
                function errorFunc() {
                    alert('Error! Please ensure you a connected to the internet and try again.');
                }
            },



        });
```

Why is the object being emptied while using validation?

Comment: @mplungjan Apologies, I've updated the code, the successFunc and errorFunc just handle redirect after successful submit. the code fails on the server side vaidation before it even reaches that function. DataFunction is an empty function I'm using to check the object.

Comment: what are you doing in validation method, can you share that method too?  Issue seems to you validation method

Comment: @mplungjan the code doesn't hit the success function so that code is not called. The problem I'm having is before the jQuery validate code is used, the object is full as expected, before the ajax is even called, it is emptied.

Comment: @QaseemSaleem I've posted the validation method, I set the validation rules before using the submit handler

Comment: @mplungjan okay, I,ve updated the question

Comment: can you use console.log(JSON.stringify(FAT)); just at the start of submitHandler before ajax request, whether it is printing some data? One more thing, does FAT is var you declared and stored the data in it?

Comment: so the log read the model but contains no values, the FAT is an object created before the validate method using different inputs in the form, reason being there complex objects eg. build an array inside of the FAT object

Comment: So your validation method is causing problem. I can't pin point the exact issue for now but you can skip validation method and check if the thing works. If so you need to fix the validation method issue.

Comment: @QaseemSaleem okay, thank you for your help. It does work without validation so I'll post an update if I find a solution, thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using built-in Unobtrusive Validation plugin?